# Wi-Fi does not work on OS X Yosemite Beta 4

Tags: macos, networking, wireless-networking, imac, osx-yosemite

When I installed OS X Yosemite Beta 4 on my 2008 iMac, it could not see any wireless networks and the button on the menu bar went crazy. When I turned it off, it did not change anything in the network's .prefpane, and vice versa.

Suddenly it got working in these days (after more then a week), but I am really interested if anybody know why it was wrong. As I saw it on the internet, I was not the only one having this problem, but there is no solution yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same issue on my early 2008 macbook pro.  This thread answered my question.  You need to download the kext that is linked to in one post and install it via the kext utility downloaded from another link later in the thread.  http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1756994

Comment: Yosemite got a lot of issues with the WiFi. For a long time now it always lost the connection somehow, but the recent update fixed them.